# Unable to connect two FlexBE states

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a beginner in FlexBE. I was able to connect the start state to initial_wait state and then initial_wait state to print_greeting state. But I am unable to connect from print_greeting state to finished state. You can see what I am trying to say from the image given below. Could anyone help?

[image: Screenshot of my FlexBE editor]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/334737/unable-to-connect-two-flexbe-states./) by [Paul Sebastian](https://answers.ros.org/users/46783/paul-sebastian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2019-10-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-07**:
Please attach your screenshot to the question directly. I've given you sufficient karma for that.

**Comment by [Paul Sebastian](https://answers.ros.org/users/46783/paul-sebastian/) on 2019-10-07**:
Okay. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I understood how to do it. The unconnected outcomes of each state are listed at the bottom of each state's visualization. First, click on the outcome (in this case click on "done" in Print_Greeting) you want to connect and then click on the target.

---

Originally posted by [Paul Sebastian](https://answers.ros.org/users/46783/paul-sebastian/) with karma: 41 on 2019-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2